# TLS Passthrough NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, tls1.2, nginx-ingress

I am trying to enable passthrough tls on a grpc application using the NGINX Ingress controller. I have configured the backend service (`lh-server`) to handle tls with its own certs.

I created the following `Ingress` resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lh-server
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: lh.demo.littlehorse.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: lh-server
            port:
              number: 5000
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - lh.demo.littlehorse.cloud
```

When I try to access the service from outside the cluster, I get the following error:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: unrecognized name"
```

I am certain that the actual TLS certs work on the backend server. I used `kubectl port-forward` to access the server, and using the same client certs, I was able to establish connection.

Comment: Did you set the controller property:  --enable-ssl-passthrough? Just checking.

Comment: Yes I did, turns out the problem was that wildcard prefixes on TLS certificates don't support multiple nested wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

**Below Troubleshooting steps will help to resolve your issue**:

1. Watch the logs for the ingress-nginx-controller and Double-check your address and ports
2. If you are using public gRPC endpoints, check  protocol buffer / gRPC build service which will assist your users to consume your API efficiently.For more information See also the specific [gRPC settings](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_grpc_module.html) of NGINX:
3. If you are running the server on another port or your cert has expired, check the port/host to determine the main server.
4. If certificates are expired you need to delete tls.cert and tls.key in your data folder. After the restart, a new certificate will be created.
5. To Fix your error either install the CA certificate in the appropriate location for the system or specify a path to certificates.